# jQuery - Pass variable to PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following jQuery:-

```
jQuery('.fancymember').on('click', function() {
    var member = jQuery(this).parent('div').parent('div').find('.test').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/get-to-know-us/",
      data: "member="+member,
      dataType: 'text',
      success:function(event){
         alert(member);
      }
    });

});
```

I want to pass the value of 'member' to a php script. If I do the following in the PHP file:-

```
<?php $test = $_POST['member'];
var_dump($test); ?>
```

The value $test is null, but the success function is alerting the correct value.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since $`test` still has a 'value' (it isn't likely `NULL`, it is more likely blank) the function will send the blank and return an event. You'll need to be more specific about your PHP value.

Comment: Where do you test the value of `$test`?

Comment: Try setting `data` using object `data: {member:member},`

Comment: Still no joy, I am using Wordpress to pass a value to a page template if that makes much of a difference?

Comment: 1. Add console.log(member) just after "var member = ..." and check what value it has before ajax request. 2. Using Firebug or something check what post parameters are passed to the /get-to-know-us/ script

Comment: Are you sure that the variable, member, has a value? The first thing I would do is put something like this right after line 2: Alert("member: " + member)